# Netlify "user is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource"

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, netlify

I'm trying to get a hand with Netlify and AWS. I have downloaded a sample REST API preset from the [official serverless site here](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb).
The site worked locally after `serverless deploy` including the `create` route, used to add new todo elements into the db (API gateway on Amazon shows no issues)

I wanted to test how would it work on netlify, so I created a bitbucket repo from the file and uploaded it into the netlify servers.
From the start, there were minor issues. Such as an error claiming that `TableName` which in code is created from `process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE` was not provided.
After replacing the value with the value of the field, I got an error saying that

> {User: arxxxx:assumed-role/aws-lambda-execute/xxx is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-xxx-1:xxx:table/serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb-dev","code":"AccessDeniedException","time":"xxx","requestId":"xxx","statusCode":400,"retryable":false,"retryDelay":30.76949318814495}

The issue suggests that my serverless parameters are wrong, however I do have the permissions set:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"
```

And all seem to work fine when the data is local.

Has anyone ever had such issue?

Comment: Are you sure the credentials are authorized to access the dynamodb you are targeting? From the messages above it looks like you may not be authorized.

Comment: @talves I can't find the authentication field in the netlify setup. Pressumed it is handled automatically by the site dependant on the contents of the serverless.yml file